# Get IP Address from TeamViewer without connecting

Tags: ip-address, teamviewer

Is it possible to know the (public) IP address of a computer where TeamViewer is ready for a remote control session - without connecting to the computer?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*Prior to TeamViewer v12, it was possible to read the partner IP from the log files without connecting, but it's not possible anymore. Since v12, you can still see the IP address in the log, but only after a successful connection (which is not that useful, since you'd have many ways to get the public IP address once you're connected).*

### For TeamViewer v12 → v13...

You need to make a successful connection, then read the logs:

- Open TeamViewer
- Fill in the partner ID, and click <kbd>Connect</kbd>

  [image: screenshot 1]
- Fill in the password, and click <kbd>Log On</kbd>

  [image: screenshot 2]
- You can now close the TeamViewer connection.
- Back on the main window, click *Extra >> Open log files...* in order to access the TeamViewer logs

  [image: screenshot 3]
- Open the `TeamViewer12_Logfile.log` file (located by default in `C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer`) (replace `12` with your version number). The log folder can be accessed from the main window by clicking *Extra >> Open log files...*
- In the file, search **from the bottom** for the first line where it is written:

  ```
   UDP: punch ignored a=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyyy
  ```

  - `a=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` → That's the IP address you're looking for!
  - `yyyyy` is the UDP port used for the connection.

---

### For TeamViewer v7 → v11

You can discover the IP address by faking a connection (partner TeamViewer must be up and running) then read the logs:

- Open TeamViewer
- Fill in the partner ID, and click <kbd>Connect to partner</kbd>

  [image: Screenshot]
- Click <kbd>Cancel</kbd>

  [image: Screenshot 2]
- Back on the main window, click *Extra >> Open log files...* in order to access the TeamViewer logs

  [image: Screenshot 3]
- Open (with Notepad or whatever) the `TeamViewer7_Logfile.log` file (located by default in `C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\Version7`) (replace `7` with your version number)
- In the file, search **from the bottom** for the first line where it is written:

  ```
   CTXX GWT.CmdUDPPing.PunchReceived, a=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, p=yyyyy
  ```

  - `a=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` → That's the IP address you're looking for!
  - `yyyyy` is the UDP port used for the connection.

Comment: I can't find "CTXX GWT...." in the log. I'm using TeamViewer 12

Comment: @sports Unfortunately TeamViewer might have changed their logs in the newer versions.

Comment: I can't find it either. This solution doesn't work any more.

Comment: It appears to only work for successful connections. :-(

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect new TeamViewer version behavior. Unfortunately, as indicated by @BaseZen, the IP address is not logged anymore if the connection is not successful (no more "faking it").

Comment: Also make sure logs are enabled: Settings > Advanced > Show Log File > "Enable Logging" & "Log Outgoing Connections".  Then you can search from the bottom of the log for "punch received" (for successful connections).

Answer (score 2):

The text to search for in the log file is the following (IP address is replaced by `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`):

`UDP: punch received a=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49518: (*)`

Comment: In TeamViewer 13, I see `UDP: connectivity: a=xxx.yyy.zzz.www p=45653: (*)` as well as `punch received` and `punch ignored`.

Comment: Also, if you're actively monitoring the log file while troubleshooting: It *does not* update until you explicitly choose **Extras** --> **Open log files...** which initiates a flush from RAM to disk.

Comment: @DavidPostill This isn't a duplicate of the answer from 2012, the text string to search for in the log file seems to have been changed in the newer version, from `CTXX GWT...` to `UDP: punch received...` All other answers posted since this one, however, *are* duplicates.

Comment: It now separates into UDPv4 and UDPv6. Easiest search string is just "punch received".

Answer (score 0):

This method is still working...

...you just have to open the `TeamViewerXX_Logfile.log` (where `XX` stands for the version number) and search from the bottom up (press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and tick the `from the bottom` radio button). Search for **a=** and there you go:

you'll find the IP-Address of the remote computer and and the UDP Port Teamviewer connects to.

Answer (score -1):

In TV12 (and probably other newer versions) you have to look for the "punch ignored a=" phrase. There is the only one which gives you unmasked IP address of the remote host.